# Where is the proper location for an application to store a large database on Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My application uses a sqlite database to store the user's content. This database can grow to be 1 GB+ for heavy users. The database is currently stored in ApplicationData (%appdata%), but the documentation for this indicates it is for roaming data which should be small, for example settings that should persist across sessions. Some other options:

- LocalApplicationData: documentation indicates this is for data that may be removed when the user logs off.
- MyDocuments/Personal: I believe this also roams.
- UserProfile: documentation says "Applications should not create files or folders at this level"

Some requirements for the storage location:

- User specific (no common areas)
- Non-administrative user must have read/write access
- Data should not roam (like AppData\Roaming)
- Data must not be deleted automatically

Many thanks for any suggestions for such a place on a Windows system.

Comment: Note that there's a simple reason that no answer can meet your requirements exactly as stated: it is possible to configure a computer so that *all* user specific data on the local disk, i.e., the entire user profile, is deleted when the user logs off.  (This is typically done when the computer is used by many different users, e.g., student computer rooms at a University.  If user profiles weren't deleted from the disk on logoff, we'd quickly run out of disk space.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user has a redirected ("roaming") application data folder and/or a redirected documents folder, it is likely that the user regularly uses multiple machines and expects his or her content to be available on whichever machine he or she is logged into.  So most likely you should use either the roaming application data folder or the documents folder.

My initial instinct was to lean towards the former, because users generally don't like seeing mysterious and/or unexpected files in their documents folder, and may be inclined to delete them.  On the other hand, the roaming application data folder is less likely to be backed up (we don't!) so, on the whole, I'd recommend the documents folder; to mitigate the other problem, put the database in a subfolder of Documents and give the subfolder a very clear name.

The local data folder is typically used for non-user-content such as caches and temporary files.  I'm not aware of any professional product that stores user content there.  IT folk are likely to take it for granted that it is safe to delete anything in these folders, and as already pointed out there are systems configured to do this automatically.

You certainly shouldn't use UserProfile; if the user profile is roaming, the content will be uploaded to the server every time the user logs out, and downloaded (if necessary) when the user logs in.  (This is *only* true of UserProfile; the roaming application data folder and other redirected folders are accessed directly from the server and never sit on the local disk.)

I don't believe that the size of the file necessarily makes a redirected folder inappropriate.  Mozilla Thunderbird, for example, stores the user's mail in the roaming application data folder, and this can get quite large.  As far as I know, this has not caused any widespread problems.

However, there are a few Windows APIs that can't be used on a networked file, and it also won't work if any of the processes that will be accessing the file are running in a different security context (e.g., as a system service).  You should check the documentation for sqlite to determine whether this is supported or not.

If you are not able to use a networked drive, I think the only good solution is to use the documents folder by default, but detect when it is on the network and ask the end user to select an alternative location.

In any event, you should provide either the system administrator or the end user (or both!) with a documented, supported way of overriding the default location.

Answer (score 3):

For a per-user store, you need the AppData/Local folder. The environment variable is %localappdata%. The .NET enum is `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`.

As for the "documentation indicates this is for data that may be removed when the user logs off."...

Yes. But it's rare. For example, it might happen for users on virtualized clients (think Citrix). In those cases, having a persistent 1GB SqlLite store will be a problem. For those of us on regular workstations, the data will probably not be removed.

Comment: %programdata% is useful, but there's only one per system, not per user.

Comment: Its `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` in .NET

Comment: Then you're looking for the AppData\Local folder. I'm looking for the way to identify that now...

Comment: Most IT folk will expect it to be safe to delete the local application data folder.  It's also likely to be excluded from backups.  For these reasons, I don't think it is appropriate for user content, and I'm not aware of any mainstream product that stores user content there.

Comment: 1GB data sounds like cached content to me. If the purpose of this is to just save data into the user's permanent data folder (whatever that means), but not to expect roaming support to duplicate that data to every workstation that the user goes to, then my answer stands. IF the expectation is that the data follows the user, then it should be in the roaming store (regardless of size). It's not rocket surgery.